# How to stop flex-box from pushing other elements out of the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

It's a bit hard to explain, but consider a flex header with a menu and then something else on the right which is fixed width. As the window size shrinks in width, there is less room for the menu. Eventually, the menu pushes the other thing out of the container.

[Working example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/jsm11482/maropte9/15/)

**Bad**

[image]

Note how the "other thing" falls out to the right.

Adding `overflow: hidden` to the menu container element makes it so the "other thing" doesn't get pushed. However, this also prevents the drop-down menu from showing, of course. I tried to work around it by setting `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: visible` but this is apparently not a valid setting.

**Better, but no drop-down menu**

[image]

(Ignore that "Item 1" has been hidden. In the real code "Item 5" would have been moved to an overflow menu -- not included in the demo here.)

**Question**

How can I make it work like the bottom example, but without adding `overflow: hidden` to the menu? That is, how can I stop flex-box from pushing the "other thing" out to the right?

Comment: Try adding `min-width: 0` to `.menu`.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin thanks, but adding `min-width: 0` causes the menu/logo to collide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71190734/how-to-stop-flex-box-from-pushing-other-elements-out-of-the-container?noredirect=1#comment125894507_71190885

Comment: Update: `min-width: 0`, perhaps in combo with something else (I don't recall) ended up working out in the end!

Answer (score 0):

Use example 2 and remove the `overflow-hidden` class. Add `min-width: 0;` to `menu` to fix overflow issues. Then set `dropdown-menu` to `display: none;`. I added a class called `item-4` to your first child of `menu`. Then you can use the following CSS to show `dropdown-menu`.

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown > div.item-4:hover ~ .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/fkwu6nj0/61/)

Comment: Thank you. However, your updates cause the menu to display behind the logo when the viewport is shrunk. See: https://i.imgur.com/hZ4Phja.png

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR. See the CodePen example linked at the bottom.

#### Limited spaces + multiple elements = unavoidably overflowing content

Your `.logo` takes up `50px` and the `.other-thing` takes up `200px`. Because you didn't set `flex-wrap` to the `.menu`, its width won't go smaller than the content. That means, as the viewport width shrinks, your .`header` will inevitably overflow.

Setting your `.menu` with `overflow: hidden;` wouldn't work in your favor either. Once your `Item 1` and `Item 5` are cropped out, your users won't be able to scroll to them because `overflow: hidden;` prohibits it.

#### `flex-wrap: wrap;` and `@media` for better responsiveness

Adding `flex-wrap` to the `.menu` would be a good start. That way, in small viewports, the `.menu` will flexibly wrap as needed. Also, to accommodate a wrapping behavior, I'd suggested you remove explicit height from `.header` and use `padding` for consistency.

Using `@media` for responsive layout will be a better long-term solution for you. Here I suggested resizing the `.logo` and `.other-thing` on smaller viewport as an example. In real life, you'd probably want to introduce a mobile-only menu UI (e.g. hamburger button) rather than keeping all menu items visible. Say, in a smaller screen (< 640px), showing `50px` logo and `200px` other thing with all those individual menu items simply won't work elegantly.

See this [CodePen example here](https://codepen.io/baadaa/pen/GROxjXO)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a simplified example. In the real world we have a mobile-friendly header/menu as you suggested. But being that the items in the menu are dynamic, we have additional code to push overflown items into an overflow menu. I'll mess around with `flex-wrap` and see if I can get it to work better with that set.

Comment: @JoshM. In that case, I'd humbly suggest you experiment with `max-width` and `overflow-x` in the middle element, so that it's scrollable when you run out of space. The unforgiving `overflow: hidden` might make it harder to work with.

Answer (score 0):

As when having a wrapper none of the solutions I could find would do the job I ended up finding that using `position: absolute` fixes the problem.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col-a,
.col-b {
  flex: 0 0 40%
}

.col-c {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}

.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1ex;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
  <li class="col col-a">
   Col A
  </li>
  <li class="col col-b">
   <div class="wrapper">
     Col B
     <div class="nowrap">
       Something to long that pushes out `Col C` to next line
       even with `overflow: hidden`
     </div>
   <div>
  </li>
  <li class="col col-c">
    Col C
  </li>
</ul>
```